# List of ObjectAnimator animation properties

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to find a list of the properties that the ObjectAnimator can animate and how it animates them.

For instance I'd like to know how the translationY property is animated. Is the value the to coordinate or is it the distance?

Comment: These QnAs should be upvoted more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectAnimators` will actually animate anything with "set" in front of the name.  So in the case of View there's `setX(float)`, `setY(float)`, `setZ(float)`, `setTranslationX(float)`, and so on.

Likewise, if you create a custom View that has their own properties, then just use `set____(type)` syntax to use an `ObjectAnimator` on it with no additional work.

Basically what they do is just call these methods at repeating intervals with values determined by the `TimeInterpolator` that is set to the `Animator`.

EDIT:

There's a lot of properties that can animate on a View, but here are a description of the more common ones.

`setX/Y(float)` - This will animate the View to the exact X or Y coordinates of the parent `View` that it is contained in.  The pixel coordinates start at `(0,0)` at the top-left corner and `(getWidth(), height())` at the bottom-right. `setY(float)` will adjust the `getTop()` of the View and `setX(float)` will adjust the `getLeft()` of the view.

`setTranslationX/Y(float)` - This will animate the View to the relative position of the `View` to where the starting point is.  So for example, if the View's `getLeft()` returns 50, then when you call `setTranslationX(25)` will move the View to the right 25 pixels to pixel 75.  Likewise, `setTranslationY(25)` will move the view down 25 pixels.  Negative values will move it left and up respectively.

`setRotation(float)` - This will rotate the `View` around the given pivot point as defined by `setPivotX(float)` and `setPivotY(float)`.  By default, the pivot point is at coordinates (0,0).  You can set it to the center by doing something like this:

```
View viewToAnimate = getViewToAnimate();
float width = viewToAnimate.getWidth();
float height = viewToAnimate.getHeight();
viewToAnimate.setPivotX(width/2);
viewToAnimate.setPivotY(height/2);
```

`setScaleX/Y(float)` - This will shrink or grow a View based on the Pivot point as described above.  A value of "1.0f" will make it normal size.  Anything less than "1" will shrink it and anything more than "1" will make it grow.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer my question though. What will "y" ACTUALLY do?  Every answer I come across leaves out very crucial information which is why I'm looking for some real documentation (which apparently there is none). For example again: what is the value actually used for? The coordinate the view will animate to or the pixel distance?

Comment: Sorry.  Editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you